# grab all images in an object with an array of images with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have been trying to grab all the source files for images and store in a single array but i am having trouble grabbing all the actual images in the array. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Here is my object example:

```
projects: { 
        "proj": [
            {
                id:"1",
                title:"Heller Recipes",
                description:"This web applications was developed to keep track of my dads recipes and make them easily accesible.He is now able to check each user and make a dinner based on what everybody likes or in some cases dont like.",
                technologiesUsed:"CodeIgniter, PHP, Sequel Pro, Javascript, jQuery,HTML5, CSS3, SASS, Foundation 5.0", 
                projectLink:"http://www.travismichael.net/HELLER-RECIPES",
                genre:"web app",
                images: [
                    {largePic:"img/projects/heller-recipes/thumb.jpg",desktopImg:"img/projects/heller-recipes/desktop.png",desktopMobile:"img/projects/heller-recipes/mobile.png"}
                ]
            },
            {
                id:"2",
                title:"3D Animation",
                description:"Created using 4D Cinema Max, a 3d anitmation program that allows you to create realistic renderings and animations.",
                technologiesUsed:"CodeIgniter, PHP, Sequel Pro, Javascript, jQuery,HTML5, CSS3, SASS, Foundation 5.0", 
                projectLink:"http://www.google.com",
                genre:"3d",
                images: [
                    {largePic:"img/projects/4dmax.jpg",desktopImg:"img/projects/4dmaxDesktop.png",desktopMobile:"img/projects/heller-recipes/mobile.png"}
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Here is my javascript so far:

```
var projLength = portfolio.projects.proj.length;

    var images = [];
    var src = [];
    for(var i=0;i<=projLength;i++){
        images.push(portfolio.projects.proj[1]);
        console.log(i);
    }
    console.log(images);
     for(var g=0;g<=images.length-1;g++){
         src.push(images[g].largePic);
         src.push(images[1].desktopImg);
         src.push(images[1].desktopMobile);
     }
     console.log(src);
```

Comment: `images[1]` should be `images[g]` I guess, same for `portfolio.projects.proj[1]`

Comment: I realize that but i was trying to debug. when i do do images[i] it returns undefined

Comment: What is `images` array expected to contain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a messy data structure to iterate.  Here's one way that does not presume to know the tags like `largePic` (it iterates whatever is there).

Step-by-step, this is what it does:

1. Iterate over the proj array
2. Get the .images property from each item in the proj array
3. Iterate over the `images` array
4. For each object in the `images` array, iterate over all properties of that object
5. Grab the value for each property in that array and add it to the output array

Code:

```
var allImages = [];
var proj = portfolio.projects.proj;

for (var i = 0; i < proj.length; i++) {
    var imgs = proj[i].images;
    for (var j = 0; j < imgs.length; j++) {
        for (var tag in imgs[j]) {
            allImages.push(imgs[j][tag]);
        }
    }
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/cy2smsn8/

If you would prefer to just directly refer to the `.largePic`, `.desktopImg` and `.desktopMobile` property names directly rather than iterating all properties that are there, that can be done like this:

```
var allImages = [];
var proj = portfolio.projects.proj;

for (var i = 0; i < proj.length; i++) {
    var imgs = proj[i].images;
    for (var j = 0; j < imgs.length; j++) {
        allImages.push(imgs[j].largePic);
        allImages.push(imgs[j].desktopImg);
        allImages.push(imgs[j].desktopMobile);
    }
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/3pzowgb9/

Comment: The problem is that i am unable to reach the all the images.

Comment: @TravisMichaelHeller - this code does grab all the images.

Comment: that works perfectly, thank you. plus i was interested to see how you would actually do this so thanks again for the reference.

Comment: @TravisMichaelHeller - I added a second option.